# Regular expression for a valid filename without extension

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression pattern to check a string for alphanumeric(a-zA-z0-9) and also can contain underscore, hypen and dot
this will be a file name so i dont want other character than this.

Comment: If it can contain a dot, won't this mean it has an extension?

Comment: that depends on your definition of extension. Does the file "dr.spock" have an extension or not?

Comment: with the string name i'll attaching the extension so dr.spock is also valid in my case

Comment: that seems to be executed under windows, so it would be useful to keep track of special files, like `prn`, `nul`, `com1`, and to exclude illegal trailing dots and spaces

Answer (score 3):

Re:

> I need a regular expression pattern to
>   check a string for
>   alphanumeric(a-zA-z0-9) and also can
>   contain underscore, hypen and dot

The pattern will be `"[_a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+"`

Note the double-backslashes, since this is first interpreted as a Java string and the backslashes need to stay intact for the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Check out ["Character Classes" in the docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#classes). Basically, `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+` should do it. If you put that in a string, be sure to escape the backslashes.

Comment: the string can also have whitespace, example "program files"

Comment: @unknown: Then add it to the range. See the link for details.

Comment: on *nix filenames can contain just about everything except "/", including control characters and the like.

Comment: @Bryan: I know, and there are lots of other valid characters even on Windows. I was just answering the question asked. :-)