# How do I check if there is a string before a a specific char

Tags: java

ill try to keep this as short as possible :)
So i have this code and its function is so make files in a directory that the user specifies. The parts of this code include:

1. Finding out the user even wants to make the file in the first place
2. Finding out the file name (Scanner, makes sure the file name has an extension)
3. Finding out the directory the user specifies (Scanner, Checks if directory user entered is valid, Checks if directory exists and if it dosen't, creates a new directory)
4. Makes file (Given that the file doesn't exist already)

My problems are in 1 and 2.

Problem in 1: The user can enter something like ".txt" and get away with making the file when in reality, you need to enter an actual name. (I made something that checks if the file has an extension. Maybe something similar?)

Problem in 2: Do while loop in beginning part doesn't quit...why...

CODE:

```
package filecreator;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class FileCreator {

public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static boolean success = false;
public static String filename;
public static String filedir;
public static String fileexten;
public static String filedir2;
public static File file;
public static File dir;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("********************************");
    System.out.println("* Welcome to File Creator 2.0! *");
    System.out.println("********************************");
    System.out.println(" ");

    //Starting prompt
    while(!success) {

        System.out.println("Would you like to create a file? Y/N?");
        String usrans = sc.nextLine();

        if(usrans.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

            System.out.println("Proceeding with file creation...");
            System.out.println(" ");
            break;

        } else if(usrans.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

            System.out.println("Exiting Program...");
            System.exit(0);

        } else if(!usrans.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || !usrans.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

            System.out.println("That is not a valid answer! Please try again!");
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Please enter a valid file name:");

    //choosing name of file
    while(!success) {

       filename = sc.nextLine();
       fileexten = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        if(filename.isEmpty()) {

            System.out.println("Please enter a file name!");

        } else if(filename.contains("/") || filename.contains(":") || 
                  filename.contains("*") || filename.contains("?") ||
                  filename.contains("<") || filename.contains(">") ||
                  filename.contains("|") || filename.contains("\"") ||
                  filename.contains("\\")) {

            System.out.println("Please do not include / \\ : * ? \" < > |");

        } else if(!filename.contains(".")) {

            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Please specify a valid file extension!");

        } else if (fileexten.isEmpty() || fileexten.contains("[^\\p{IsDigit}\\p{IsAlphabetic}]")) {

            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Please specify a valid file extension!");

        } else {

            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("File name \"" + filename + "\" chosen");
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Where would you like to have your file saved?");
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid directory");

    //finding directory if directory exists and creating one if it dosent
    while(!success) {

        filedir = sc.nextLine();
        dir = new File(filedir);

        do {

            System.out.println(""
                    + "That is not a valid directory");
            filedir = sc.nextLine();

        } while((!filedir.contains(":") && !filedir.contains("\\")));

        System.out.println("Checking to see if directory exists...");

        if(!dir.exists()) {

            System.out.println("Directory does not exist! Would you like to create one? Y/N?");
            String usrans = sc.nextLine();

            if(usrans.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

                dir = new File(filedir);
                success = dir.createNewFile();

                if(!success) {

                    System.out.println("Created!");
                    break;

                } else {

                    System.out.println("Something went wrong! Aborting Program...");
                    System.exit(0);
                } 

            } else if(usrans.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

                System.out.println("Directory not created! Aborting program...");
                System.exit(0);

            } else if(!usrans.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || !usrans.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

                System.out.println("That is not a valid answer!");
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Looking to see if \"" + filename + "\" already exists...");

    file = new File(filedir,filename);

    if(file.exists()) {

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("\"" + filename + "\"" + " already exists! Closing Program...");
        System.exit(0);

    } else {

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("\"" + filename + "\"" + " doesn't exists! Creating now...");
        file.createNewFile();
        success = file.createNewFile();

        if(!success) {

            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("\"" + filename + "\"" + " successfully created!");

        } else {

            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Error! File not created");
        } 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Sounds like you need a regex

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver can you plz elaborate?

Comment: Which loop doesn't exit? Can you post an example of your input, and what printout repeats?

Comment: @MufasaKing the answers below give a more detailed explanation. Let me know if you have other questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1: Use the following for checking the validity of the file-name instead of those long conditional clauses.

```
if ( filename.toLowerCase().matches( "[a-z0-9_-][a-z0-9_.-]*\\.[a-z0-9]+" ) )
```

Solution 2: Because your program expects the user to enter ***n*** to quit, rather than finishing by itself.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question you can create a [regex to validate the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059591/regular-expression-for-a-valid-filename-without-extension):

```
boolean validFilename = filename.matches("[_a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+"); //regex to validate a filename

if(!validFilename){
   //output error to user and ask to try again
}
```

For your second question, you are asigning your `success` variable to false and you are not changing its value. Then your while condition `while(!success)` will always return true and your loop will run *"forever"*

Comment: its not the while loop that is stuck. its the do while loop right after dir is declared as a new file